# How to get ONLY the latest files in dir and subdir?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm currently struggling with powershell again.
I **only** need to extract the latest directory date and file date in that directory, subdirs included.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\ -Force -Recurse | 
select -Property fullName, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime | 
Export-Csv "C:\path\to\.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

With this code I only get everything in that directory, but it's more than 7TB and this feels like it lasts forever.

Do you have any ideas, how to get only the newest directory and files?

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest directory :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\ -Force -Recurse -Directory | 
Sort-Object  LastWriteTime -Descending | 
select -First 1 -Property fullName, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime
```

To get the latest file :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\ -Force -Recurse -File | 
Sort-Object  LastWriteTime -Descending | 
select -First 1 -Property fullName, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime
```

Comment: I can't believe this worked. Got it already, but in another way. Thanks man!

Comment: EDIT: Ok, this doesn't work for the whole directory. Only for specified directories like P:\test\

Comment: Do you mean the full drive ? Because it works with a directory and its subfloders

Comment: Yes, the full drive. Is there another possibility?

Comment: Do you get a error ? Do you really have to read the whole drive ?

Comment: No, there are no errors. When I try to export it as an .csv, the file is just empty... (0KB)
And yea, I have to read the whole drive.

Comment: I don't know. 
It works on a external disk drive and I get permission errors when I run it on a share